# How to install NUPKG files?

Tags: model-view-controller, package, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have an error in my solution that I need the WebMatrix.Data.dll

I downloaded the WebMatrix.Data and I got the NUPKG files but there is no dll file. I already changed the extentsion of the .nupkg to .zip I extracted it and still no .dll file of webmatrix.

How to use the NUPKG files? how to install it so I can obtain the dll?

Answer (score 0):

Only the oldest version (1.0.20105.407) of the [WebMatrix.Data NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebMatrix.Data/1.0.20105.407) has a WebMatrix.Data.dll.

The newer versions of the WebMatrix.Data NuGet package install the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data/) NuGet package which includes a newer version of the WebMatrix.Data.dll.